# Dataframe: Unable to save cell value with .at or .loc

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having an issue while assigning values to pandas data frame cell with `.at`. For example:

```
u55.at[idx, 'cb_testid'] = new_val
df_pivot.at[save_idx, 'sample_nr'] = sample_nr
```

This returns the correct value if I print a specific index, example `u55.at[1, 'cb_testid']`, but printing the column or data frame, the old values are returned.

How could I get the proper values in my df?

Comment: Did you make sure you are overwriting the correct index? For example the index could be `1` as an `int` or `1` as a `str`

Comment: Can you provide the code where you set the new value and the code where you print the value including its output?

Comment: The code is too long to print, basically no change is implemented in the df cell.

Comment: Can you provide a short example which has the same behaviour as you described?